# python 3 replacement for dircache?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Before I go reinventing the wheel, can anyone tell me if there's a drop-in (or semi-drop-in) replacement for the single-line statement:

```
allfiles = dircache.listdir('.')
```

Comment: You could probably fairly easily update the Py2.7 version to Py3k: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/2.7/Lib/dircache.py

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't understand why dircache was removed when there is obviously no alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line? No. But you can just do:

```
global_cache = {}
def cached_listdir(path):
    res = global_cache.get(path)
    if res is None:
        res = os.listdir(path)
        global_cache[path] = res
    return res
```

Comment: Just adding to that answer, because other people might come here via search: https://pymotw.com/2/dircache/ states, that the directory is re-read when the modification date changes. This doesn't happen in this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
@lru_cache(32)
def cached_listdir(d):
     return os.listdir(d)
```

This is not an identical replacement.  The warning that Dschoni issues in the [comment on viraptors answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622596/python-3-replacement-for-dircache/41108963#comment70300135_32622739) applies here too: the directory is not re-read when the modification date changes, so if files get added or removed from the directory, later calls will be incorrect.