# How to remake this python3 dircache/cmd python3

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, module

i am wondering how to go about making this short test in python3, cmd is supported in python3 but dircache is not... currently only works on python2 but looking to change it to work in python3, thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cmd
import dircache

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = '(MyCmd)'

    def do_test(self, line):
        print('cmd test ' + line)

    def complete_test(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        """ auto complete of file name.
        """
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) < 2:
            filename = ''
            path = './'
        else:
            path = line[1]
            if '/' in path:
                i = path.rfind('/')
                filename = path[i+1:]
                path = path[:i]
            else:
                filename = path
                path = './'

        ls = dircache.listdir(path)
        ls = ls[:] # for overwrite in annotate.
        dircache.annotate(path, ls)
        if filename == '':
            return ls
        else:
            return [f for f in ls if f.startswith(filename)]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    mycmd = MyCmd()
    mycmd.cmdloop()
```

Ive tried using this instead of dircache but had no luck

```
@lru_cache(32)
def cached_listdir(d):
     return os.listdir(d)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python 3 replacement for dircache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622596/python-3-replacement-for-dircache)

Comment: @Mureinik I have tried that but it did not work using functools, so i dont think so

Answer (score 0):

Here you go check out the load function

```py
import os
import glob
import cmd

def _append_slash_if_dir(p):
    if p and os.path.isdir(p) and p[-1] != os.sep:
        return p + os.sep
    else:
        return p

class MyShell(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = "> "

    def do_quit(self, line):
        return True

    def do_load(self, line):
        print("load " + line)

    def complete_load(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        before_arg = line.rfind(" ", 0, begidx)
        if before_arg == -1:
            return # arg not found

        fixed = line[before_arg+1:begidx]  # fixed portion of the arg
        arg = line[before_arg+1:endidx]
        pattern = arg + '*'

        completions = []
        for path in glob.glob(pattern):
            path = _append_slash_if_dir(path)
            completions.append(path.replace(fixed, "", 1))
        return completions

MyShell().cmdloop()
```